# How do you limit only 1 decimal entry in a UITextField in Swift for iOS8?

Tags: ios, swift, ios8

I have searched all around for this but still cannot seem to get it to work. I have a simple iOS program with a UITextField that converts Farenheit to Celsius and Kelvin. I am trying to limit only 1 decimal entry in this UITextField. For example 98.9 is ok but 98..9 is not.

This is the function in which I want to limit only 1 decimal. What I would like is if 1 decimal is entered then it will not allow another 1 to be entered but numbers can still be entered after the first decimal of course.

```
       func farenheitButton(sender: AnyObject)
      {
        var fVal = self.farenheitTextLabel.text
        var cVal = self.celsiusTextLabel.text
        var kVal = self.kelvinTextLabel.text

        if let fVal = self.farenheitTextLabel.text?.toDouble()
        {
          var fValx = self.farenheitTextLabel.text
          var fDoubleValue : Double = NSString (string: fValx).doubleValue

          var fToC = (fDoubleValue - 32) * (5/9) //convert Farenheit to Celsius formula
          var fToK = ((fDoubleValue - 32) / (1.8000)) + 273.15 //convert Farenheit to Kelvin formula

          //create string from value with a format
          var afToC : Double = fToC
          var bfToC : String = String(format:"%.4f",afToC)

          var afToK : Double = fToK
          var bfToK : String = String(format:"%.4f",afToK)

          celsiusTextLabel.text = bfToC
          kelvinTextLabel.text = bfToK
        }
      }
```

Comment: 1)The code you've provided is just performing the conversion, there is nothing here that you are doing with the text field to limit the type of characters being entered. (hint - text views have useful delegate methods). 2)`fValx`, `fToC`, `bfToK`; seriously? Can you see how clear full variable names such as `celsiusTextLabel` are compared to those terse and unreadable examples? It's good practice to use descriptive names for methods, classes and variables. Write code for humans to read and let the compiler worry about opitimisations.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can set the `UITextField.delegate = self` and use the `textField(textField: UITextField,shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange,replacementString string: String)` method to do what you want.

The following code will not allow you to enter more than **1 decimal point** in the textfield.

```
func textField(textField: UITextField,shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange,replacementString string: String) -> Bool
{
    let countdots = textField.text.componentsSeparatedByString(".").count - 1

    if countdots > 0 && string == "."
    {
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. What would I pass into the parameters for NSRange and String though?

Comment: you don't have to. read the the first line. just set the `textfield.delegate = self`, if you are putting the above code in self.

Comment: if anyone is unclear on this or delegating, through the delegate in the viewDidLoad and then add this method in the class and change all "textField.text"s to your actual text field name

Answer (score 5):

You should add `UITextFieldDelegate` to `class ViewController`:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
...
}
```

then

If name of your `@IBOutlet` is `textField`, (it could looks like:
`@IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!`), then add

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.textField.delegate = self

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }
```

after that you could use:

```
func textField(textField: UITextField,shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange,replacementString string: String) -> Bool
{
    let countdots = textField.text.componentsSeparatedByString(".").count - 1

    if countdots > 0 || textField.text == "."
    {
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use this subclass of UITextField. It uses the same principle as the answers above, but with a little bit clearer code.

```
class WMNumberTextField: UITextField, UITextFieldDelegate {

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        delegate = self
    }

    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        guard let text = text else { return false }
        let dots = text.characters.filter { $0 == "." }

        return dots.count == 0 || string != "."
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift 3

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField,shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange,replacementString string: String) -> Bool
{

    let countdots =  (textField.text?.components(separatedBy: (".")).count)! - 1

    if (countdots > 0 && string == "."){
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used below code to limit 1 decimal entry in swift 3.0.

```
let inverseSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn:".0123456789").inverted
let components = string.components(separatedBy: inverseSet)
let filtered = components.joined(separator: "")

if (textField.text?.contains("."))!, string.contains(".") {
   return false
}
return string == filtered
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4:**  This works !

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        guard let counter = textField.text?.components(separatedBy: ".") else { return false }
        if (counter.count - 1 > 0 && string == ".")  { return false }
        return true
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**For swift 5 to restrict text field to enter only one (.) decimal.**

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        if string == "." {
            let countdots = textField.text!.components(separatedBy: ".").count - 1
            if countdots == 0 {
                return true
            } else {
                if countdots > 0 && string == "." {
                    return false
                } else {
                    return true
                }
            }
        }
        return true
    }
```